# Intensity Wise Gradient is not working in leaflet.heat

Tags: leaflet, heat-map

I am using leaflet.heat for creating heatmap with leaflet API.I have a highest intensity of 1.0 and lowest 0.0. When I am drawing a heatmap in the highest zoom its all are showing the same color. I have plotted the value over the heat color. Here you can see what I am getting in the attached Image. Here is the code I am using. Seems like Intensity is not working and using all value as same.

```
var heatmap = L.heatLayer(allHeats, {
                radius: 20,
                max: 1.0,
                blur: 15,              
                gradient: {
                    0.0: 'green',
                    0.5: 'yellow',
                    1.0: 'red'
                },
                minOpacity: 0.7
            }).addTo(map);
```

allHeats Array data

```
[23.703161, 90.414101, 1],
[23.722657, 90.412525, 0.6],
[23.701936, 90.415782, 0.5],
[23.722099, 90.413981, 0.9],
[23.703582, 90.414536, 0.3],
[23.699689, 90.421493, 0.1],
[23.705727, 90.412281, 0.8],
[23.720692, 90.414056, 0.2],
[23.706133, 90.412448, 0.8],
[23.704677, 90.41166, 0.7],
[23.703912, 90.413993, 0.4]
```

[image]

Comment: Please show an example of your allHeats array or put up a mimimal working example in codepen, jsfiddle or similar. It is impossible to debug a static image.

Comment: I have just updated as you need the allHeats Array data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already find out the issue. There is a bug which was not fixed in the github master branch of leaflet.heat. Probably owner did't notice. There is a pull request but that is not committed in the master branch of leaflet.heat. See this [discussion](http://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat/issues/74) and [pull request](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat/pull/78) where you can find out the solution. Instead of using the master branch the HeatLayer.js use this code of [HeatLayer.js](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat/commit/ca1f43026545f7e413c653e376b1fa8bf3a2b6a6) for the actual result.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with Leaflet.heat, as far as I can see. I think you have too few points and too small a radius for any meaningful spots to be formed by the heatmap. I have created a [working example in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5wz63tbn/1/), which also incorporates the example from the [leaflet.heat github demo page](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat/tree/gh-pages/demo), whereby on mouse over, points are added to the heatmap. You can see from this, that the heatmap code is working. I think, for such a small number of points as you have, you probably want to increase the **radius** to something like 30, so that more points are considered part of each cluster.

Here is the additional code from draw.html:

```
map.on({
   movestart: function () { draw = false; },
   moveend:   function () { draw = true; },
   mousemove: function (e) {
      if (draw) {
         heatmap.addLatLng(e.latlng);
      }
   }
})
```

Here is a screenshot from the jsFiddle:

[image: heatmap]